# gltext screensaver font size

Tags: ubuntu, screensaver

Is it possible to change the font-size of text in a gltext screensaver? I'm using gltext as implemented by Ubuntu 10.04/gnome.

Answer (score 0):

gltext is an ordinary program residing in /usr/lib/xscreensaver/. Running it with the --help option you can see all of its settings:

```
peter@antec:~$ /usr/lib/xscreensaver/gltext --help
GLText: from the XScreenSaver 5.10 distribution (07-Sep-2009.)
        http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/

Options include: -root, -window, -mono, -install, -noinstall, 
         -visual <arg>, -window-id <arg>, -fps, -no-fps, -pair, 
         -text <arg>, -program <arg>, -spin <arg>, -no-spin, 
         -wander, -no-wander, -front, -no-front, -delay <arg>, 
         -wireframe, -no-wireframe.
```

As far as I can see, there is no option for font size.

Answer (score 0):

Current versions of gltext (i.e. from the 5.42 XScreensaver distribution, 28-Dec-2018) include a "scale" option that is used to adjust the size. From `man gltext`:

> -scale  Sets the scale at which the text is rendered.  Bigger values will result in bigger text; smaller values will result in smaller text.  The default value is 0.01.